# Determine fill percentage of loaded trailer based of photo

Tags: c#, .net, image, ocr, analysis

Any suggestions how you can determine the fill percentage of a loaded trailer if you take a picture of the trailer from the dock?
Any API's? Algorithms?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built `GetTrailerFillPercentage(Bitmap)` method if that is what you are asking.

You could perhaps create such a method, but it would almost guaranteed involve a fair bit of image analysis. Because of this it would be highly dependent on the input data.

To device a reasonable algorithm you probably need to answer:

- What part of the image is trailer and background?
- What part of the trailer is filled?

In the ideal case you would have a black background, a white interior trailer wall, and pink boxes. Making the segmentation easy.

The problem also depend on the angle of the photo. A side image might be fairly easy to analyze, and image along the length might be impossible. After all, how can you know how long the trailer is if you can only see a wall of boxes a short distance inside.

In the end there is far to little information to provide any actual recommendations. I would recommend starting to think about what limitations you have with regards to cameras, their limitations, placement, and other possible sensors. Reading a bit on the topic of image analysis, or talking with an expert might also be useful.